# Calculating normals for lighting in opengl

Tags: opengl, normals

I have two quads for which I need to find the normal.The co-ordinates are as follows
for quad 1:

```
(-2,1.25,-1)
(-2,2.2,0)
(1,2.2,0)
(2,1.25,-1)
```

I have got the normal as (0,.73,-.69)

for quad 2:

```
(-2,2.2,0)
(2,2.2,0)
(2,1.25,1)
(-2,1.25,1)
```

normal:(0,.73,.69)

I have already calculated the normals.Can someone please confirm whether these normals are correct?

Also I read about normal pointing inwards and outwards..would someone explain that concept to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your normals basically look correct. For the first quad, I get:

```
(0.0, 0.725, -0.689)
```

For the second one:

```
(0.0, -0.725, -0.689)
```

As you can see, I got the opposite sign for the second normal. Which leads directly to the second part of your question.

The term "outwards" does not really make sense for a isolated quad. It is mostly applied to closed shapes, where it should make intuitive sense. Picture a sphere, with a normal vector drawn starting at a point on the sphere. The normal pointing "outwards" means that it points away from the center of the cube, which means that it points to the outside. "inwards" is then of course the opposite, where the normal points towards the center of the sphere, or to the inside of the shape.

There's another way of looking at it, since normals are mostly used for lighting calculations. The normals need to point to the side of the surface that you want to see lighted. Most often, you look at shapes from the outside, so you want the outside lighted. Which means that you mostly want the normals pointing outwards. If you have open surfaces that need to be lighted when viewed from either side, there are slightly more complex lighting calculations that can handle that, which are typically found under "two-sided lighting".

There's a related concept that is also important here, which is the "winding order". It defines if the vertices are arranged clockwise or counter-clockwise when viewing them from a certain direction. OpenGL uses the winding order to decide if a triangle faces the viewer. Again, you care about having the desired winding order when looking at the surface from the outside, or more generally from the side you want to see when you display the surface. OpenGL uses counter-clockwise winding by default, so you want counter-clockwise winding when looking at a surface from the side you want to be visible, which for closed shapes is mostly from the outside. You can often get away with the winding order being "wrong" if you don't eliminate backwards facing triangles, which is done with `glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE)`. But in any case, you can save yourself from running into problems later if you always use a consisting winding order for your primitives.

This leads us back to the normal calculation. Since only the sign ended up different, none of our calculations are technically wrong. I assumed that the quads used counter-clockwise winding, which means that I see the "outside" of the quad from the direction where the vertices appear in counter-clockwise order. Since I also want the normals pointing towards the outside, I calculated the normals that way. In other words, with the normal I calculated, if you move away from the quad in direction of the normal, and then look back at the quad, the vertices would be in counter-clockwise order.